# Gremlin for CosmosDB - Cannot create ValueField on non-primitive type GraphTraversal

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, gremlin, tinkerpop

I'm trying to execute a query but facing this error. Below query is the simplest form of what I was trying to achieve.

```
g.V('Users12345').as('u').
  project('id', 'email', 'test').
    by('id').
    by('emailId').
    by(where(values('id').is(eq(select('u').values('id')))))
```

I was trying to use select inside project. What's that I'm missing here?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? It looks like you're trying to compare the user's id with the user's id, expecting a boolean value as the result (which would always be `true`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The invalid part is `eq(select('u').values('id'))`. I guess "the query in its simplest form" means that you're aware of it being pointless. Assuming that `u` is actually not the same user that's being projected, you probably want to do something more like this:

```
g.V('Users12345').as('u').
  project('id', 'email', 'test').
    by('id').
    by('emailId').
    by(coalesce(where(eq('u')).by('id').constant(true), constant(false)))
```

Comment: Superb. It worked like a miracle. Thanks a lot, Daniel. Agreed that I struggled a bit in explaining my problem and great that you got it. Appreciate it. Thanks again.