# Conditionally set a property value on edge when adding a vertex [GREMLIN API]

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

Im trying to add a vertex that will be linked to another vertex with a conditional property value in between their edges.

So far this is what i came up with:
 - this runs with no errors but im not able to get any results.

```
g.V().has('label', 'product')
   .has('id', 'product1')
   .outE('has_image')
   .has('primary', true)
   .inV()
   .choose(fold().coalesce(unfold().values('public_url'), constant('x')).is(neq('x')))
       .option(true, 
           addV('image')
               .property('description', '')
               .property('created_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15')
               .property('updated_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15')
               .property('pk', 'f920a210-fbbd-11e9-bed6-b9a9c92913ef')
               .property('path', 'product_images/87wfMABXBodgXL1O4aIf6BcMMG47ueUztjNCkGxP.png')
               .V()
               .hasLabel('product')
               .has('id', 'product1')
               .addE('has_image')
               .property('primary', false))
       .option(false, 
           addV('image')
               .property('description', '')
               .property('created_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15')
               .property('updated_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15')
               .property('pk', 'f920a930-fbbd-11e9-b444-8bccc55453b9')
               .property('path', 'product_images/87wfMABXBodgXL1O4aIf6BcMMG47ueUztjNCkGxP.png')
               .V()
               .hasLabel('product')
               .has('id', 'product1')
               .addE('has_image')
               .property('primary', true))
```

What im doing here is im trying to set the `primary` property of newly added edge in between `image` vertex and `product` vertex, depending on whether a `product` is already connected to an `image` where the edge already has a `primary` set to true.

if a `product` already has an `image` with an edge property: `primary:true` then the newly added image that will be linked to the product should have an edge with property `primary:false`

Seed azure graphdb:

```
//add product vertex
g.addV('product').property(id, 'product1').property('pk', 'product1')

//add image vertex
g.addV('image').property(id, 'image1').property('public_url', 'url_1').property('pk', 'image1');


//link products to images

g.V('product1').addE('has_image').to(V('image1')).property('primary', true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that your traversal runs without errors as I hit several syntax problems around your use of `option()` and some other issues with your mixing of `T.id` and the property key of "id" (the latter of which might be part of your issue in why this didn't work as-is, but I'm not completely sure). Of course, I didn't test on CosmosDB, so perhaps they took such liberties with the Gremlin language.

Anyway, assuming I have followed your explanation correctly, I think there is a way to vastly simplify your Gremlin. I think you just need this:

```
g.V('product1').as('p').
  addV('image').
    property('description', '').
    property('created_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
    property('updated_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
    property('pk', 'f920a210-fbbd-11e9-bed6-b9a9c92913ef').
    property('path', 'product_images/87wfMABXBodgXL1O4aIf6BcMMG47ueUztjNCkGxP.png').
    addE('has_image').
      from('p').
    property('primary', choose(select('p').outE('has_image').values('primary').is(true), 
                          constant(false), constant(true)))
```

Now, I'd say that this is the most idiomatic approach for Gremlin and as I've not tested on CosmosDB I can't say if this approach will work for you but perhaps looking at my console session below you can see that it does satisfy your expectations:

```
gremlin> g.V('product1').as('p').
......1>   addV('image').
......2>     property('description', '').
......3>     property('created_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
......4>     property('updated_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
......5>     property('pk', 'f920a210-fbbd-11e9-bed6-b9a9c92913ef').
......6>     property('path', 'product_images/87wfMABXBodgXL1O4aIf6BcMMG47ueUztjNCkGxP.png').
......7>     addE('has_image').
......8>       from('p').
......9>     property('primary', choose(select('p').outE('has_image').values('primary').is(true), constant(false), constant(true)))
==>e[31][product1-has_image->25]
gremlin> g.E().elementMap()
==>[id:31,label:has_image,IN:[id:25,label:image],OUT:[id:product1,label:product],primary:true]
gremlin> g.V('product1').as('p').
......1>   addV('image').
......2>     property('description', '').
......3>     property('created_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
......4>     property('updated_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
......5>     property('pk', 'f920a210-fbbd-11e9-bed6-b9a9c92913ef').
......6>     property('path', 'product_images/87wfMABXBodgXL1O4aIf6BcMMG47ueUztjNCkGxP.png').
......7>     addE('has_image').
......8>       from('p').
......9>     property('primary', choose(select('p').outE('has_image').values('primary').is(true), constant(false), constant(true)))
==>e[38][product1-has_image->32]
gremlin> g.E().elementMap()
==>[id:38,label:has_image,IN:[id:32,label:image],OUT:[id:product1,label:product],primary:false]
==>[id:31,label:has_image,IN:[id:25,label:image],OUT:[id:product1,label:product],primary:true]
gremlin> g.V('product1').as('p').
......1>   addV('image').
......2>     property('description', '').
......3>     property('created_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
......4>     property('updated_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
......5>     property('pk', 'f920a210-fbbd-11e9-bed6-b9a9c92913ef').
......6>     property('path', 'product_images/87wfMABXBodgXL1O4aIf6BcMMG47ueUztjNCkGxP.png').
......7>     addE('has_image').
......8>       from('p').
......9>     property('primary', choose(select('p').outE('has_image').values('primary').is(true), constant(false), constant(true)))
==>e[45][product1-has_image->39]
gremlin> g.E().elementMap()
==>[id:38,label:has_image,IN:[id:32,label:image],OUT:[id:product1,label:product],primary:false]
==>[id:45,label:has_image,IN:[id:39,label:image],OUT:[id:product1,label:product],primary:false]
==>[id:31,label:has_image,IN:[id:25,label:image],OUT:[id:product1,label:product],primary:true]
```

If that looks right and this doesn't work properly in CosmosDB, it is because of line 9 which utilizes a `Traversal` as an argument to `property()` which isn't yet supported in CosmosDB. The remedy is to simply invert that line a bit:

```
g.V('product1').as('p').
  addV('image').
    property('description', '').
    property('created_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
    property('updated_at', '2019-10-31 09:08:15').
    property('pk', 'f920a210-fbbd-11e9-bed6-b9a9c92913ef').
    property('path', 'product_images/87wfMABXBodgXL1O4aIf6BcMMG47ueUztjNCkGxP.png').
    addE('has_image').
      from('p').
    choose(select('p').outE('has_image').values('primary').is(true), 
           property('primary', false), 
           property('primary', true))
```

I find this approach only slightly less readable as the `property()` doesn't align with the `addE()` but, it's not a terrible alternative.

Comment: I like your answer as it simplified my query but it doesnt work in cosmosdb yet.
It says `Gremlin Query Execution Error: Cannot create ValueField on non-primitive type GraphTraversal`

Comment: I tried another way by following the suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54571806/gremlin-for-cosmosdb-cannot-create-valuefield-on-non-primitive-type-graphtrave) 

i used coalesce instead of the choose traversal you used at the end:

`coalesce(select('p').outE('has_image').constant(true), constant(false))`

but still the same error.

Comment: it seems azure cosmos db hasnt supported this yet. look [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v2/issues/566)